# How to update each row of a column from one table with a list of values from another?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a table A with records with 1 column only that are random alphanumerical characters.  That table has say 10 rows.

I have another table B with 10 rows also that I want to take a value from a row from table A and apply it to a row in table B.

So basically, take a value from Table A and assign it to a row in table B.  Preferably, take the value from table A row 1 and assign it to table B row 1, etc...

I am using SQL Server.

We can take any value from table B to assign to a row in table A.  We just can't re-use a value from table B.

Here are the 2 tables in it's simplest form for this example:

CREATE TableA ([Value] NVARCHAR(50))

CREATE TableB ([Value] NVARCHAR(50))

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. What DBMS are you using? What have you tried so far? In which way do you want to map "row 1 from A" to "row 1 from B" because it all depends on how you sort the data. What's the structure of table B?

Comment: Thank you.  I have updated my question.

Comment: What have I tried?  This only:  UPDATE TableA SET Value = (SELECT * FROM TableB).  Obviously the inner SELECT is wrong and returns multiple values.  I don't know how to tell SQL to go from record 1 to 10 in a simple query without any WHILE loop.

Comment: What do you mean by "assign to a row" - you mean update the value of a column? how are you joining the two tables? You can't update a column used by the join criteria, but you only have a single column? Sample data and expected results please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempA (stringEntry NVARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO #tempA (stringEntry) VALUES ('abcd'), ('efgh'), ('ijkl');

CREATE TABLE #tempB (stringEntry NVARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO #tempB (stringEntry) VALUES ('mnop'), ('qrst'), ('uvwx');
```

You can do the following:

```
SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY #tempA.stringEntry) AS RowNumber,
  #tempA.stringEntry AS entryA
INTO #tempA2
FROM #tempA;

SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY #tempB.stringEntry) AS RowNumber,
  #tempB.stringEntry AS entryB
INTO #tempB2
FROM #tempB;

UPDATE #tempA 
SET #tempA.stringEntry = #tempB2.entryB
FROM #tempA
INNER JOIN #tempA2 ON #tempA.stringEntry = #tempA2.entryA
INNER JOIN #tempB2 ON #tempB2.RowNumber = #tempA2.RowNumber;
```

This assumes that you have equal number of rows in each table, as you indicated, or are okay with having the "excess" entries in your first table not being updated.